# Nginx Config - Use a Variable for the domain name

Tags: nginx

I have the following Nginx Block of code. Actually I have block of code around 50 time for different sites.

I wanted to see if I could combine it into one block of code. You will see test.dating in the code 5 times. Is there a way to replace the domain name 'test.dating' with a variable?

www.thai.dating

Just want to reduce the number of server blocks.

Cheers
Adam

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using variables in Nginx location rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416957/using-variables-in-nginx-location-rules)

Comment: You want to combine all server blocks into one?

Comment: BTW, there must be no space between `=` and `404` in `try_files`. It should be `try_files $uri =404;`

Comment: nginx does not support variables in config files, as per http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html