# nginx "env" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I use `nginx` with `docker-compose` and want `docker-compose` to pass `SERVER_NAME` to `nginx` as an environment variable. I created the following nginx configuration file:

`myconf.conf:`

```
# Environment variables are used to dynamically set SERVER_NAME
# from docker-defined environment variable. This logic  is stolen from:
#
# https://docs.apitools.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf.html
# https://github.com/wantedly/nginx-image-server/blob/master/files/nginx.conf

env SERVER_NAME;

upstream django {
    server workflows-django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    perl_set $server_name_from_env 'sub { return $ENV{"SERVER_NAME"}; }';
    server_name $server_name_from_env;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    perl_set $server_name_from_env 'sub { return $ENV{"SERVER_NAME"}; }';

    server_name $server_name_from_env;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/bostongene.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/bostongene.key;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 75M;

    location /media {
        alias /srv/workflows/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/workflows/static;
    }

    location / {
        # We can talk to upstream django either via uwsgi or just http proxy

        # uwsgi:
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;


        # http proxy:
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_pass http://django
    }
}
```

For some reason, nginx is cursing about that `env` directive:

```
2016/08/26 13:02:39 [emerg] 1#0: "env" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:7
```

Here's my Dockerfile, where you can see that this config is used as nginx default site:

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx \
                        ca-certificates \
                        gettext-base

COPY myconf.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY myconf.crt /etc/ssl/private/
COPY myconf.key /etc/ssl/private/

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Why?

---

**ANSWER**: let me exlain, what was the problem in detail. `myconf.conf` file was used as `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, which is NOT the root nginx config. The root nginx config is`nginx.conf` and it includes `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` in `http` context:

```
http {

    ...
    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

so my `env` statement is in fact in `http` context, which is incorrect - it should be written in root context only.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/577370/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-nginx-conf

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I've read that post 10 times over - there's no direct answer. Seems like there's nothing wrong with `env` in my config, it's just nginx messed up so that it doesn't recognize its own directives from the core module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416957/using-variables-in-nginx-location-rules.

Comment: If you're interested specifically in what's wrong with your config rather than what you shall do, here's an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://bot.ngx.cc/logs/%23nginx/2015/01-January/%23nginx.01-31.log (googled with "nginx bug "env directive is not allowed here"") has given me the answer.

As testified by the presence of the [`server` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html)<sup>1</sup>, this is not your main configuration file but a chunk to be included, most probably in the `http` [context](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure). While [`env`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env) is only valid in the `main` context.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>as the link shows, there are a few types of the `server` directive, none of which are valid in the `main` context</sub>

Comment: Ivan, you're right! I replaced `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` with this script, but it is indeed imported by nginx.conf in `http` context. I should've modified `nginx.conf` instead of default. Thanks a lot!